# Project Reunion - Application won't complile

Tags: visual-studio, windows-app-sdk

I had a solution built with Project Reunion (0.8 preview) which was compiling and running fine. My visual studio and extensions did an update and now the application now doesn't compile, with 9 error messages, all variations of below

I've tried creating a new project with no changes but the same errors occur.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   NU1201  Project Reception is not compatible with uap10.0.17763 (UAP,Version=v10.0.17763). Project Reception supports: net5.0-windows10.0.19041 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)   Reception (Package) C:\Users\Ceri.Turner\OneDrive - David Lloyd Leisure\Documents\Visual Studio\Reception\Reception\Reception (Package)\Reception (Package).wapproj 1

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   NU1201  Project Reception is not compatible with uap10.0.17763 (UAP,Version=v10.0.17763) / win10-arm. Project Reception supports: net5.0-windows10.0.19041 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)   Reception (Package) C:\Users\Ceri.Turner\OneDrive - David Lloyd Leisure\Documents\Visual Studio\Reception\Reception\Reception (Package)\Reception (Package).wapproj 1

I've tried googling and the error appears to relate to UWP which i'm not using, so am confused.
When i created the project, the template used was "Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop)"

Comment: well it  seems you need to update your dependencies, if you use nuget packages you need to check those too. maybe look at the .wapproj file  and change some refs there.

Comment: All extensions show as up to date

Comment: thats not the point, if you have a ref to an older version of a dll and something changed between the version u use and the one that vs is now get  then stuff breaks. PRISM is a good example for that, stuff moves between namespaces  and you need to figure that in your code. That can be  painful ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change the target and minimum versions to a later windows version then it compiled fine